# Facebook js sdk add tab dialog, is there a way to lets the user type the custom tab name?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

When i dialog come, it only show pages of the user but don't lets the user type the name of this tab.

Is there a way to do it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently possible.  I think it would make a great enhancement request. File it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post back here with the bug number so others who come across this stackoverflow question can easily find the enhancement request.